# in OpenGL, why does my camera see z=-1 or z=0 but not z=-2?

Tags: opengl

I am following a simple tutorial on the web, displaying a square, with vertices (-1, -1, 0), (1, -1, 0), (1, 1, 0), (-1, 1, 0).

Things work fine.
Then I replace the z=0 by z=-1 for all 4 vertices. Things still work fine.

Then I replace z=-1 by z=-2. And I don't see the square any longer. z=-1.25 doesn't work either.

I thought the camera was at (0, 0, 0) looking at negative z. What is going on?

Comment: the default clipping volume at the very end of the pipeline is from [-1,-1,-1] to [+1,+1,+1]. Unless you make some transformations (like an orthographic or perspective projection matrix, which will transform your points into that cube) all things beyond that cube will be clipped

Comment: If you are unsure whether this is your problem, make sure to add some code to the question (especially the setup of projection and modelview matrices)

Comment: @Paul-Jan thanks but I didn't have any projection, forgot to mention it

Comment: @Thomas: It seems to me you have a fundamentyl misunderstanding of how the rendering pipeline works and I'm afraid, the answers and comments given won't probably help you. What is your background? Do you know how clip-space and viewport transformations work?

Comment: @thokra Im beginning. is this correct? objects in a "real space" -> z buffer -> projection -> clip (-1,-1 -> 1, 1) -> viewport (to fit screen). But I still don't know about the answer below (why clip to a cube)

Comment: @Thomas: I'm afraid it's not. I'll come up with something more detailed.

Comment: @thokra thanks but this question becomes out of bounds. let me read up more tutorials and get back to you, as I had just started and thought there was a simple answer for my original question

Comment: @thokra after reading, is it: real space (x, y ,z, w) -> clip (-1..1) -> remove z, w -> to screen coordinates -> color shader -> z buffer test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a "camera" is useful, but as a simplification of what really happens, it can be little misleading at times.  After the vertex data is transformed to "clip space", the resulting primitives get clipped to a cube from -1..+1 on each axis.  Any primitives outside the cube are discarded completely.

So it is by design that anything at z=-1.25 or z=+2 etc. is not rendered.

In a normal application, your vertex shader (or modelview and projection matrix, if you are using legacy OpenGL) must transform the objects you want to render so that they fall inside that cube.  For perspective rendering, you can either consider the cube to use homogeneous coordinates, or you can think of clipping as happening after Z division.

Comment: I don't understand: why clip to a cube and not to a surface ? (e.g z=0)
as it is rendered to a screen ultimately

Comment: @Thomas: The depth information must be preserved to allow for depth testing. That's why.

Comment: @datenwolf so everything finally in -1..+1 (x,y,z) will: 1/ do depth test  2/ project x,y,z to x,y 3/ viewport render of x,y. right?

Comment: Note: the z-clipping can be disabled in OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: @Thomas: The order is this: First the (x,y,z,w) data is projected to (x,y,z).  Then it is clipped to the cube, and after that it is transformed to device coordinates.  The depth test happens later, after some other steps, depending on how you set things up.

Comment: @DietrichEpp how does the z is accounted in for the transformation to device coordinates ?

Comment: Device coordinates are 2D.  The depth varies over the fragment just like other outputs from the vertex shader (all your texture coordinates, colors, or whatever).  You can also modify it in the fragment shader if you make it a fragment shader output.